# Highcharts stacked column is cut off

Tags: highcharts

The first stack of my column chart is not fully visible.

[image: Chart without max value defined]

The only solution I found was to add a max value on the y-axis.
Bu that is not an ideal solution because the max remains even when I disable a series by clicking on it in the legend.

[image]

Here is an [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/31g0jqyr/2/).

```
{
chart:{
    type: 'column'
},
plotOptions: {
    column: {
    stacking:"normal",
    grouping: false
  }
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
    text: ""
  },
  labels: {
  
  },
  allowDecimals:true,
  gridLineColor:"#DDDDDD",
  endOnTick:false,
  max:null
},
xAxis:{
    type: "datetime",
  min:1609459200000,
  softMax:1638316800000,
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {month:"%b",year:"%Y"},
  labels: {y:20},
  title:{text:null},
  gridLineColor:"#DDDDDD"
},
series:[{
    name:"Solar power",
    data:[{
  x:1609455600000,y:40.328},{x:1612134000000,y:108.824},{x:1614553200000,y:58.224}],
  color: "rgba(255, 174, 1, 1)",
  id:"del-solarPhotovoltaic"
  },
  {
  name:"Delivered Electricity",
  data:[{x:1609455600000,y:327.583405},{x:1612134000000,y:238.927913},{x:1614553200000,y:54.12531}],
  color:"rgba(96, 189, 104, 1)",
  id:"del-electricity"
  },
  {
  name:"Natural gas",
  data:[{x:1609455600000,y:4073.892843},{x:1612134000000,y:2768.81114}],
  color:"rgba(93, 165, 218, 1)",
  id:"del-naturalGas"
  },
  {
  name:"Exported Electricity",
  data:[{x:1609455600000,y:-19.093318},{x:1612134000000,y:-68.414876},{x:1614553200000,y:-37.718392,}],
  color:"rgba(96, 189, 104, 1)",
  id:"exp-electricity"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your x-axis min value: `1609459200000` is greater than the first data point `x` value: `1609455600000` and Highcharts doesn't take into account the first column when calculating y-axis extremes (treated as if it were outside the chart).

Similar situation presented here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b1oucLne/

```
    xAxis: {
        min: 4,
        max: 40
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        data: [{
            x: 2,
            y: 4073.892843
        }, {
            x: 6,
            y: 2768.81114
        }]
    }]
```

As a solution reduce or remove `xAxis.min` property.